# How to customize swagger-ui content in Nuxt3

Tags: nuxt.js, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, nuxt3

I was writing the API document in Nuxt3 with Swagger-UI and I have a question.

How to customize swagger-ui content in Nuxt3?

I set the following settings in `nuxt.config.ts`.

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    nitro: {
        experimental: {
            openAPI : true
        }
    }
})
```

And the swagger-ui is shown on `http://${host}:${port}/_nitro/swagger` successfully.

But the content is not what I want.

The main reason is that some parameters in the POST Body must be included, but they are not mentioned in the swagger-ui.
[image]

I checked some information on the Internet, including Nitro, Nuxt3, swagger-ui and other websites, but I couldn't find where I can fill in these customized information?

I have tried adding the code below in `@/server/api/auth.post.ts` but it has no effect at all.

```
/**
 *  @swagger
 *  /api/auth:
 *      post:
 *          summary: hello
 *          description: world
 *      responses:
 *          200:
 *              description: !!
*/
```

Thanks for reading my question.

Comment: Exactly. I am also looking for an answer. Have you found an answer to this?

Comment: I asked the same in the community, is not possible for the moment, the module is still in its early stages: https://github.com/unjs/nitro/blob/main/src/runtime/routes/openapi.ts